# Passing List<int> with more then 10 lac records in function parameter?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a situation where I have more then 10 lac record in database.
and I when a user hit my action method in MVC with some selected records I want to check whether these records are present in database or not by fetching all the record and comparing them with record passed by user.

then I want to pass all those record to an another function.
Is it safe to pass so many record in a function parameter??

Here is a demo :-

```
    //Action Method

    [HttpGet]
    Public ActionResult SaveRecords(List<int> selectedRecords)
    {
        List<int> allRecordsFromDB = _db.GetAllRecords();
        if(allRecordsFromDB.Contains(selectedRecords))
        {
            _Process(allRecordsFromDB); //here I am passing more than 10 lac devices to a function as parameter
        }
    }

    Private void _Process(List<int> allRecords)
    {
        //Do some process here 
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: does "lac" means something special (feels like it related to number)?

Comment: You should match the records at database level only, design your database query or a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** it will be safe.

As Phil said "As it is a list you are only passing a reference to the list of items and not the actual items themselves."

**another solution** is you can put all records in session or cache(according to your use-case) and can access anywhere ..no need to pass the records as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. As it is a list you are only passing a reference to the list of items and not the actual items themselves.